# Glob match file or root

Tags: glob

I need a Glob pattern to match all files in `api/db/seeds/` folder or the `README.md`, this one is at the root of the project. I came up with the following pattern `{**/seeds/*,README.md}`, but it isn't working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: "it isn't working": what is the difference from what you want?   It looks like the ** is in the wrong place to find all files under api/db/seeds/, shouldn't it be `api/db/seeds/**` ?

Comment: Actually the last `*` matches all files under the seeds dir. At least that's what I guess is doing.

Comment: IF api/db/seeds/ contains subfolders, THEN api/db/seeds/* won't find files in the subfolders.  (Is that the problem?  If not, what is it doing differently from what you want?  Maybe give an example if it is hard to describe.)

Comment: Now, it's matching nothing. What i want to include in the glob pattern is: all files inside seeds dir *and* the README.md file in the root dir.

Comment: Which implementation of glob?  If gnu bash, `shopt -s globstar` enables **.

Comment: I'm running this in an .sh file, in a ubuntu machine.

Comment: ** may not be supported by the shell processing the script.  I think ** is not included in POSIX Shell Command Language.  I think on Ubuntu /bin/sh may point to /bin/dash, which also does not support **.  /bin/bash only supports ** after enabling it as above.

Comment: I think POSIX and /bin/dash also do not support {A,B} syntax.

Comment: So how would you approach it? @user9712582

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246327/discussion-between-user9712582-and-vencho).